# issue changing height with jQuery and waypoints.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have a fixed position footer that gets it's top position from a jquery function. Using waypoints, when I scroll down so #main is 'bottom-in-view' I cannot get the height of the footer to change. Anyone have any ideas? Ultimately this will need to slide down and reveal more footer content. [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqP2j/) Is there anyway to animate height on a fixed position element?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
        var position = function () {
            var w = $(window).height();
            var f = $('footer').height();
            var foo = (w-f);
            $('footer').css('top', foo);
        };
        $(document).ready(position);
        $(window).resize(position);

        if (screen.width >= 768){
                $('#main').waypoint(function(direction) {
                    if (direction === 'down') {
                        $('footer').css({'height': "500px"});
                        alert('hit rock bottom');
                    }
                }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' })
                .waypoint(function(direction){
                    if (direction === 'up') {
                        //$('footer').animate({height:'110px'},300);
                    }
                }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
        }
    });
```

Comment: you dont need to enclose your jquery function second time with $(function(){}).

Comment: yup got it. was splicing together chunks and forgot to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executing correctly and the footer to be assigned the larger height of 550.  However, because it has `position: fixed` the rest of the height is displayed off the bottom of the screen.  Calling `position()` after adjusting the height will fix your issue.

See the fix here:  http://jsfiddle.net/VxqNa/

Note, if you use the jQuery `animate()` function, you must call `position()` after the animation is completed by passing a function to be used as a `complete` handler.  For example:

```
$('footer').animate({height:'110px'},300,'swing', position);
```

Comment: very cool. Now I will try and figure out how to get it to expand from top down, instead of from bottom up. thank you very much